# ¿Cómo colorear una fila de un datagridview que no tiene celdas vacías en c#?

Tags: c#, datagrid, color

Lo que tengo que hacer es colorear una fila, cuando se llene toda la fila.

Comment: Hola .Cristhian Yovani Garcia ., te saludamos y te damos la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, por lo tanto **te sugiero modificar tu pregunta, agregar lo que has realizado, más información, etc**, saludos!

Comment: Hola @Cristhian Yovani Garcia Covarr por favor para que te podamos ayudar agrega algo de código que intentaste para encontrar la solución.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te pongo un pequeño ejemplo de como cambiar el color de una fila cuando todas sus celdas contiene valor. Esta comprobación la he puesto en el evento **RowValidated**

```
private void dataGridView1_RowValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is DataGridView datagrid)
        {
            bool completa = true;
            DataGridViewRow row = datagrid.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
            {
                if (row.Cells[i].Value == null)
                {
                    completa = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = completa ? Color.Aqua : DefaultBackColor;
        }
    }
```

Espero que te sirva como guia.

Un saludo

Comment: Disculpa y si me sale un error en datagrid, yo le cambie por el nombre de mi grid.