# Colorear el texto de una celda en DataGridView C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, datagridview

¿Cómo puedo cambiar color del texto dentro de una celda de un DataGridView?

Les comento actualmente creo una DataTable con el cual lleno el DataGridView. Pero al momento de la creación del DataTable realizo un serie de validaciones para saber si ese dato sera cambiado de color para lo cual tomo la posición y la almaceno en otro DataTable1.

El primer DataTable lo asigno en el DataSource del DataGridView, Para después cambiar el color las celdas con el otro Databla1 con el siguiente código.

```
private void DataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e){
        if (Indicador.AsEnumerable().Any()){
            foreach (DataRow celda in Indicador.Rows){ /// Recorre las posiciones marcadas para pode cambiar el color de la celda

                this.dataGridView1.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(celda["Posicion"].ToString())].Cells[celda["Columna"].ToString()].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            }

        } 
    }
```

El detalle con este código es que cuando utilizo el ordenamiento de las columnas se mantiene el color en la celda y no se cambia junto con la fila.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asi es como funciona, el problema que cuando preciono el ordenamiento en el header de la celda, pasa lo siguiente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Revisa esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/172801/822 y usa la propiedad FontColor en lugar de BackColor, me late que funcionará

Comment: Debes usar el evento [CellFormatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting?view=netframework-4.8), para que el color se actualice cada vez que lo haga el `DataGridView`. Siguiendo el enlace tienes un ejemplo muy claro de como hacerlo.

Answer (score 0):

puedes probar con este codigo:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

Obviamente en el 0 de rows indicas tu fila y en el 1 de Cells indicas tu celda.

Edit: Disculpa, no habia visto lo de abajo. Deberias ponerle a cada fila una forma de identificarlos(un ID por ejemplo) luego, en el evento reordenar del datagrid, volver a pintar(vas a tener que buscar cada ID en las filas y pintar la celda de esa fila)